# Javascript reorder HTML element based on attribute value

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" id="item-1">
    
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="item-2">
    
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="item-3">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

And in javascript I'm currently applying filters & sort to the results of an array:

```
results = Object.keys(list).filter(.....);
results = results.sort((a, b) => (....) ? 1 : -1);

// After the results have been filtered & sorted, hide all HTML elements:
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(i => i.classList.add('d-none'));

// And then proceed to show only the results that have been filtered & sorted:
results.forEach(index => 
{
    let id = list[index].id;
    let item = document.getElementById('item-' + id);

    item.classList.remove('d-none');
});
```

This works great. The problem is that now I need to move the HTML elements according to the `results` array, specifically with the `id` field.

**A) Expected output**: Array ids [2, 1]

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" id="item-2">

    </div>
    <div class="item" id="item-1">

    </div>
    <div class="item d-none" id="item-3">

    </div>
</div>
```

**B) Expected output**: Array ids [2]

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" id="item-2">

    </div>
    <div class="item d-none" id="item-1">

    </div>
    <div class="item d-none" id="item-3">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When is it A, when B?

Comment: And what is `results` and what is `list`? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hope my answer helps. Also voting for a easy reusable snippet next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I had several problems:

The first one was instead of using `Object.keys(results).filter` I should be using `results.filter`, because I don't need to get only the Keys, which was making things way harder.

Secondly, the logic to apply in order to have everything re-organizing according to multiple filters is:

1. Sort / filter everything
2. Hide all items (using `d-none`)
3. Grab all the wrapper children `const wrapperItems = wrapper.children`
4. Create a variable named `wrapperNewItems` that holds the new sorted/filtered items
5. Create a variable that holds which ID's (item-1, item-2, etc) have been sorted/filtered
6. Push the items sorted into the variable and remove `d-none`
7. Push the items that were NOT sorted into the variable and keep `d-none`

Translated into code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(i => i.classList.add('d-none'));

const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
// Saves the existing children
const wrapperItems = wrapper.children;
// Holds the new items ordered perfectly
let wrapperNewItems = [];
// Holds names that were filtered (item-1, item-2, etc)
let listOfNamesFiltered = [];

// Shows only the items filtered
results.forEach(item => 
{
    let name = 'item-' + item.id;
    let el = document.getElementById(name);

    el.classList.remove('d-none');

    wrapperNewItems.push(el);
    listOfNamesFiltered.push(name);
});

for (let i = 0; i < wrapperItems.length; i++)
{
    let item = wrapperItems[i];
    let name = item.id; // id="" already contains "item-{id}"      

    // If the name already exists in the list, we won't add it again
    if (listOfNamesFiltered.includes(name))
        continue;

    wrapperNewItems.push(item);
}

// Clears the div
wrapper.innerHTML = '';

// Appends the items once again
for (let i = 0; i < wrapperNewItems.length; i++)
    wrapper.innerHTML += wrapperNewItems[i].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to

1. iterate the result ids and get the correspondig object from the dom (combined with your last .forEach round removing the d-done class)
2. get all d-done elements and combine both lists
3. convert to html and reset innerHTML of the wrapper

```js
let results = [2,1]

let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper-id')

wrapper.innerHTML = results.map(id => document.querySelector('#item-' + id))
                  .concat([...document.querySelectorAll('.d-none')])
                  .map(elem => elem.outerHTML)
                  .join('')
```

```html
  
  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-id">
  <div class="item" id="item-1">
      item-1
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item-2">
      item-2
  </div>
  <div class="item d-none" id="item-3">
      item-3
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `results` does not hold the `ID` but yes the `index` of the array element. It does not match the `item-{id}`. But I fixed that issue, however, I don't get your `map(elem => ...)` and it doesn't work properly. I'm gonna create a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can move elements to the top, using `prepend` function.

On bellow example, I only implement the logic about move elements, and I didn't protected against non existent elements.
You should add your logic's about filtering, etc. and protect for possible errors.

```js
function sortDivs() {
  let list = [2, 1];

  let mainDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper')[0];
  list.reverse().forEach(n => mainDiv.prepend(document.getElementById('item-'+n)));
}
```

```css
.item { 
  border: black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" id="item-1">
    item-1
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="item-2">
    item-2
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="item-3">
    item-3
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button onClick="sortDivs()"> sort DIVs</button>
```

Comment: Reverse? Why the use of reverse? I don't want to reverse per say, it should match the criteria the user defined.  Doesn't work properly, since it's missing stuff like removing the `d-none` class. Still your solution, is better than what I currently have. and I have made some improvements, but still I have to fix some problems.

Comment: Because I'm moving to the top one by one. The last move, must be the first element of the array, for that element stay on the top. Like I said, I only implemented the logic about moves. You should add others logics that you need. For the `d-none` class, you can add the calss to all div.item, and remove one by one when it is moved